# Add two label at the corner diagonally

Tags: ios, swift

How to add two label in the view at the corner diagonally , like in the pic.

[image: label]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What code have you got at this point?  Those images are not diagonal they are square/rectangular with clear areas using the alpha values of the image.

Comment: I was trying to add two label and rotate them

Comment: How?  Show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess in that example they are images over the top of the main image however if you really want to rotate a label you can set it's transform like this:

```
let radiansAngle: CGFloat = 45.0 * .pi / 180.0
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radiansAngle)
```